# Card(x) on the Ordinals and Choice

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Defining card(x) in general requires the Axiom of Choice.  But suppose one wishes merely to assign a cardinal to every ordinal.  Does this require Choice?  If so, can one get by with a weakening of it, such as that the countable union of countable sets is countable?  Thanks.

Comment: No choice is required. For an ordinal $\alpha$, $|\alpha|$ is simply the smallest ordinal $\kappa\le\alpha$ such that there is a bijection between $\alpha$ and $\kappa$.

Comment: Thanks!  Goldrei ("Classic Set Theory", p. 252) suggests that there is a problem assigning a cardinal to epsilon_0 without assuming some form of Choice.  Does Choice simply lower the cardinality of that ordinal?  Or perhaps he is simply pointing out that assigning cardinalities in general requires AC (even if one could say that epsilon_0 is countable without it).

Comment: I just looked at the book, and it appears that Goldrei uses AC to prove that the union of countably many countable sets is countable. But you actually don't need that general fact to prove that $\varepsilon_0$ is countable; the fact that $\varepsilon_0$ is countable can be shown in ZF without any use of AC.  (The countings you need can be defined outright.)

Comment: Thanks!  That's very helpful -- I felt quite confused by his comment.

Comment: @Mitchell: Thanks; I don’t have access to the book and was wondering what Goldrei was actually doing there.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I see where OP was coming from.  Goldrei says: "Let us assume a weak form of AC and get an insight into the size of $\varepsilon_0,$ in the next, fairly long exercise." He doesn't come out and say explicitly that AC is needed, but he doesn't say otherwise, so a reasonable reader might assume that AC is needed for the entire result (rather than just for the specific way he carries out the proofs in the exercise).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scott%27s_trick#Application_to_cardinalities ​ ​